# PSTR macro expansion in another macro arduino

Tags: arduino

I have an issue. This is my macro:

```
#define LOG_NOTICE(fmt,args...)  log(NOTICE, __FUNCTION__, PSTR(fmt), ## args)
```

That's log function:

```
template<typename... Args> 
static void log(Level level, const char* module, const char* fmt, Args... args){
  if (level >= getLogLevel()){
      sprintf(MessageBuffer, fmt, args...);
      sprintf(OutputBuffer, "[%12ld] [%10s] [%10s] %s",
        millis(),
        asString(level),
        module,
        MessageBuffer
      );

    Serial.println(OutputBuffer);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I have following output without any message when `LOG_NOTICE("test: %d", 1)` is called:

```
[          75] [    NOTICE] [     setup]
```

When macro `PSTR` is deleted from macro `LOG_NOTICE` I see expected result, but I want to read string from flash instead of ram. Also when function is called directly:

```
log(NOTICE, __FUNCTION__, PSTR("test: %d"), 1);
```

I see message in output.

So my question is what is wrong with first `LOG_NOTICE` macro expansion and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use:

```
sprintf_P(MessageBuffer, fmt, args...);
```